# Windows Phone: How to put another control at the bottom of a dynamic listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scrollview

I have a listbox that is showing a dynamic list of data that can grow. At the bottom of this listobx, once the user has scrolled through all the items, I want to show a piece of text. And sometimes, depending on the situation, it can be a button or another listbox. But, I want to learn how to put a textbox first. I tried searching forums and tried, Grid, StackPanel, ScrollViewer. Nothing seems to work. This code here, looks promising but I am not able to scroll with this: This must be a common UI, I would guess. Any help?

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="tasteePic" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="I'm Hungry" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <StackPanel Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <ListBox Name="MenuItemListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"  SelectionChanged="MenuItemListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image
                            Margin="4, 4, 4, 4"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding ThumbNailUrl}" />
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BusinessName}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Neighborhood}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Test" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place your TextBox after the ItemsPresenter element of the ListBox by retemplating in Blend.

Here's a worked example.

[How to add a Control at the end of Items of a ListBox (e.g. a "Load More" Button or Hyperlink)?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/cdf2716d-0ceb-4c03-9e26-cbe9f53328d8)